# amsbook improvement

Tags: babel, incompatibility, amsbook

Today it was the first time I tried `amsbook` class and I noticed a (possible?) bug (or should I say incompatibility?)

`babel` with `brazil` option translates *Chapter* to *Capítulo*. So note the accented letter.

Well, `amsbook` class produces CAPíTULO.

Checking line 990 in `amsbook.cls` we find

```
\uppercase\@xp{\chaptername}\enspace\thechapter}
```

and the upper case is the problem. (by the way, what is `\@xp`?)

OK, it is possible to redefine that part of `\@makechapterhead` to fix the problem but **is there any chance to have an updated version of the class in the future**?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{amsbook}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

%% original code
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{\global\topskip 7.5pc\relax
  \begingroup
  \fontsize{\@xivpt}{18}\bfseries\centering
    \ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\m@ne
      \leavevmode \hskip-\leftskip
      \rlap{\vbox to\z@{\vss
          \centerline{\normalsize\mdseries
              \uppercase\@xp{\chaptername}%  <----- here
              \enspace\thechapter}
          \vskip 3pc}}\hskip\leftskip\fi
     #1\par \endgroup
  \skip@34\p@ \advance\skip@-\normalbaselineskip
  \vskip\skip@ }
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\chapter{title}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It should be `\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}`, but it could have other consequences. Can you add a MWE to play with?

Comment: @egreg, done! Yes, I agree, your code would work.

Answer (score 4):

You can make a patch to use `\MakeUppercase` instead of `\uppercase\@xp`.

It's a good idea to load `textcase` along with `amsbook`, particularly if accented characters are expected.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}
  {\uppercase\@xp}
  {\MakeUppercase}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Abcdéf}

text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I posted the question so maybe they could update the class. Thanks for let me know about `textcase`.

Answer (score 3):

amsbook should use MakeUppercase (or the excellent textcase package as proposed by egreg:-)

However babel's brazil option could use a form that would work with `\uppercase` if it used `\'{i}` rather than `\'{\i}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{amsbook}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}




\begin{document}
\def\chaptername{Cap\'{i}tulo}

\chapter{title}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I just discovered that you are the author of `textcase`. Glad to meet you!

Comment: This wouldn't work for languages using `\={\i}` that cannot be obtained with `\={i}` without defining a new composite. Or languages with more complicated settings, such as Greek or Russian that *need* `\MakeUppercase`.

Comment: @egreg But I gather Brazilian Portuguese isn't one of them so that's OK:-)

Comment: @egreg I agree amsbook should/could change but babel perhaps has an easier update cycle and this would be enough for some languages at least.